# Mutilple SELECT in one query

Tags: sql, select, union

I am using 3 tables: **projects**, **project_manager** and **project_employee**

**projects**

```
 - project_id (int, PK)
 - project_name
```

**project_manager**

```
 - project_id  (int, PK)
 - manager_id  (int, PK)
```

**project_employee**

```
 - project_id  (int, PK)
 - employee_id  (int, PK)
```

Assume that a manager is currently logged in (so we know what is his ID), what I trying to do is write a query that will display a grid-view showing:

project_id, project_name and number of employees in project,

for example:

```
Project ID              Project Name                  Number of employees
     1                  Test Project                           3
     2                  Government Fund                        5
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS employee_number, NULL AS Unnecessary_Column
FROM [project_employee] 
WHERE project_id = @pID
UNION 
SELECT [projects].project_id, [projects].project_name 
FROM [projects], [project_manager] 
WHERE [project_manager].project_id = [projects].project_id AND [project_manager].mag_id = @mID
```

but the result is not as what I am expecting ... what I was getting with my query is 2 columns employee_number and Unnecessary_Column with messed up data.

Comment: What result are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @ElGavilan The result I want is on my question, what I was getting with my query is 2 columns employee_number and Unnecessary_Column with messed up data.

Comment: Why people voted this down and want to close it, is there anything wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query instead

```
SELECT           projects.project_id,
                 projects.project_name,
                 count(*) as NumberOfEmployees
FROM             projects
INNER JOIN       project_manager manager ON projects.project_id = manager.project_id 
INNER JOIN       project_employee emp ON projects.project_id = emp.project_id  
WHERE            manager.manager_id = @mId            
GROUP BY         projects.project_id,projects.project_name
```

Comment: it always give an empty result, can you check it again?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited the query